# Avoiding retzuot of tefillin (shel yad) from tangling while wrapping

Tags: tefilin, rashi, rabbeinu-tam

I don't know if others have this same issue, but it happens to me often that while wrapping the רצוע of the תפלין של יד around my arm, that it gets tangled up and I need to straighten it every few coils before I can continue.

Now that I recently started to wear פצפונים (i.e. small pairs of רש"י and רבינו תם תפלין that you wear both at the same time) and I have to wrap two רצועות simultaneously, this issue has now doubled!

Any (proven) techniques to avoid this?
I can't wrap one after the other since the custom is to wrap them together at the same time.

Comment: Straighten them out before wrapping?

Comment: @shmosel that only helps partially. But because of the circular movement around the arm, it still happens a bit.